# iOS multiline label not gong to multi-line in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to set this up and have always done this in code and would like to get this done in modern version of Xcode 7.3.

I do the following steps:

1. drag out a UILabel
2. set the number of lines to 0
3. set Line Breaks to Word Wrap

[image]

But this isn't breaking and representing all the data. The data is being populated though. What else do I need to do?

[image]

#### edit 2

added border for this

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the height of the label is tall enough for a third line of text?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog how would I check - maybe throw a border on it? I thought the Label grows in response to the size of the text / copy by default.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog added a screenshot with border

Comment: You need to check out matt's answer and use auto layout to set constraints of your labels, also you can get the height of the text (1, 2, 3,etc. lines) to set the height constraint of your label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do this in code, your label is not using auto layout. But when you drag into the storyboard, your label *is* using auto layout, so the rules are different. You need to add constraints.

What you do now depends on what you want. First you'll need constraints for top and left of the label. Then, if you add constraints for just width, the label will grow downwards as it fills with text. If you add constraints for both height and width, the label will simply fill up within that size.

Comment: thx matt! - love your books btw (4 / 5 era). haven't been doing much iOS recently

Comment: hey, so I updated with the minimum constraints for my label (top,left,and width as seen above in edit #3) but still not growning downwoard. I had disabled size classes as this is only targeted for iPhone. I also removed the labels that were beneath temporarily in case they were affecting in any way. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I know it's some bone-head answer but it's driving me crazy.